# Cant load maven projects in eclipse on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, maven, ubuntu

I have just installed the newest version of eclipse on my ubuntu 16.04. But every time I try to import a maven project I get this kind of errors shown on the picture.

Also, all dependencies and plugins has `.lastUpdated` sufix, which means I guess that there is some kind of a problem and it wasn't downloaded correctly. I've tried removing everything from .m2 folder and letting eclipse download dependencies again, didn't work. Also tried to add `<maven-resources-plugin>` explicitly in the `.pom` and that didn't help also. Tried using both embedded maven from eclipse and installing my own from terminal, and setting eclipse to work with that, but no luck.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like a proxy/firewall issue...

Comment: @khmarbaise how can i go about it?

Comment: check proxy in "Network" Eclipse configuration + check proxy in Maven setting.xml and "Maven" Eclipse configuration + >clean install -U

Comment: if Maven force Update do not work, clean your .m2 folder

Comment: @sgrillon in "network connections" in eclipse, active provider is set to native, although i tried direct, and manual and it didn't work. In /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml proxies are commented out. Maven force update didn't work, and neither was cleaning .m2 folder...

Comment: if you execute `mvn clean install` out of Eclipse?

Comment: @sgrillon I got https://imgur.com/M8EFDG6

Comment: And I fixed that tag warning appearing in the picture, and now I got only the bottom error.

Comment: Your setting.xml is broken, you have a XML problème (tag not close, ...) line 109 column 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiiinally 7 hours later I figured it out. What I had to do was to change jdk. Initially I installed it from terminal and the exact name of it was `java-8-openjdk-amd64`. That somehow made a problem to maven and it couldn't download dependencies.

Once I removed the current version of java, downloaded `jdk-8u171-linux-x64.tar.gz` from Oracle-s website, extracted it into `eclipse-installer/jre` before installation, deleted everything from `.m2` so those `.lastUpdated` files will be removed, it finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem few month ago, and the only way was to remove Maven Integration Plugin from Eclipse and re-install it from the marketplace.

Comment: Will try, but I tried to compile outside of eclipse and had the same error.

Comment: Which JDK are you using ? I faced problem with JDK 10, but It works great with JDK 8. Do you have a special configuration in `~/.m2/settings.xml` ?

Comment: I am using java-8-openjdk-amd64. I messed around a bit with proxies, but nothing more that that, now `settings.xml` is the way it was by default. Although it's not located in `~/.m2/settings.xml`, but in `/usr/share/maven/conf`.

Comment: You should display your proxy configuration to be sure you configured the https correctly.

Comment: If you think in `settings.xml`, it's commented out. I didn't make any changes to proxy configuration.